# PIC microcontroller PORT not changing logic states

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I tried to run the following code on both the PIC16f690 and the PIC16f19176. All the code should do is turn off and then turn on PORTA. I also tried turning on then off PORTA. However PORTA never changes so whatever I first set it as is what it stays at. Eventually once I fix this PORTA will be used as the 8 bits for a 16x2 lcd and then PORTB will be used for the other lines. So when I send a command to the 16x2 lcd I need to be able to set `PORTA = 0b00000001;` for example and then keep switching it.

```
void main(void) {
     TRISA = 0b00000000;
     ANSEL = 0b00000000;
     ANSELH = 0b00000000;
     while(1){
        PORTA = 0b00000000;
        __delay_ms(5000);
        PORTA = 0b11111111;
        __delay_ms(5000);
    }
    
    return;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note, most 16x2 LCDs have a "nibble" or 4-bit mode. If you can use that, then it will free up four pins.

Comment: Yeah I might use that in the future if I do not have enough pins. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Try switching the pins without anything connectd to them. There might be a capacitor on the lcd somewhere and it take longer to switch, Thats all i can think of. And, another sugestion would be to not use the delay(), you may have missed adding its library somewhere, and it just stops the code after the first switch. Instead of delay() try a big for() loop inside a for() loop for long delay.

Comment: I only used an led for testing that still did not work. I could try changing the delay though

Comment: Does the PORTA register change in your debugger? If it does, then the problem is hardware-related, otherwise software. Similarly you should be able to write straight into the register from the debugger, just to test some pins.

Comment: Is your clock set up correctly? Since you can set the state initially, perhaps your delay is taking much longer than you expect.

Comment: I don't see you doing any bank selection. Does the compiler take care of that automatically?

Comment: Just a quick question to eliminate dumb errors: does your MCU even run at all? (pointing finger at clock)

Comment: @Ilya Yes I can turn on PORTA pins but then they never change states from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1

Comment: Do these chips support LATA?  Some PIC variants want outputs to go to special "latch" banks, while PORTx is used for inputs.

Comment: Try delays with smaller values, like 100. Also make sure XTAL frequency is defined. I also suggest to start a debugging session and step the code line by line.

Comment: It's better to use LAT registers instead of PORT ones when writing output values. But here, this is not the problem.

Comment: @Tagli only when you (also) write to individual bits.

Comment: @Tagli Ok so I changed the delay to a total of 1000ms and it seems to turn on and off. However if you look at the image I posted above that is the output of pin RA5. Im not sure why the pin goes high for a very short amount of time (72ms, the red question marks),

Comment: It should be 50% on and 50% off but there is an extra 72ms on period

Comment: Do you have any ISRs setup?  Maybe post your whole code.

Comment: Have you switched off the WDT?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the data sheet, **no output** is shown for RA0, but **RA1 has output ability**. Perhaps you should try another port or pin for test? In any case, **you cannot use PORTA for 8-bit parallel data output**!. The killer is RA3, which is *input-only*.

[image: 16f690 data sheet]

 But on the other hand, the block diagram in the same data sheet shows that RA0 should be configurable as a **digital output**. The only other odd thing about RA0 is its ability to serve as an *ultra-low-power-wake-up*...with a programmable current sink. RA0 is also in-circuit-serial-programming data pin, but that *shouldn't* matter after a reset.

[image: 16f690 data sheet RA0 block diagram]